# use python or awk to find all core elements with specific suffix

Tags: python, awk

python list format:

```
list1=['a', 'a','b', 'b','c','c','c','d']

list2=['a_1_p', 'a_2_p', 'b_1', 'b_2_p', 'c_1', 'c_2', 'c_3','d_3_p']
```

output1:

```
["a","d"]
```

a tab format(try use awk)

```
a_1_p a
a_2_p a
b_1   b
b_2_p b
c_1   c
c_2   c
c_3   c
d_3_p d
```

output:

```
a_1_p a
a_2_p a
d_3_p d
```

I wanna extract the core element (in list1) all with "_p" in list2.
Note: these core element must all contain "_p" in list2, in my example, "b" not meet the condition.

Here is my solution:

```
c=[]
result=[]
for i in set(list1):
    c.append({i:[n for n in list2 if n.startswith(i)]})

for n in c:
    lst=list(n.values())[0]
    if all(x.endswith("_p") for x in lst):
        result.append(list(n.keys())[0])
```

output:

```
['a', 'd']
```

quite a bit of code.

Is there a more easily "AWK" way?

Any suggestion that you can provide is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an awk. (updated)

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[NR]=$0;next} $0~!/_p/ {b[a[FNR]]=1}  $0~a[FNR] && $0~/_p/ {c[++t]=$0" "a[FNR];x[t]=a[FNR]} END {for (i=1;i<=t;i++) if (b[x[i]]!=1) print c[i],b[x[i]]} ' 1 2
a_1_p a
a_2_p a
d_3_p d
```

This part is run for firt file `1` only

```
NR==FNR {a[NR]=$0;next}
```

It stores value using number so

```
a[1]=a
a[2]=a
a[3]=b
a[4]=b
a[5]=c
a[6]=c
a[7]=c
a[8]=d
```

Then for the second file `2` first test

```
$0~!/_p/ {b[a[FNR]]=1}
```

If line does not contain `_p` set a array `b` to `1`

```
line_1 a_1_p b[a[1]]=b[a]=0
line_2 a_2_p b[a[2]]=b[a]=0
line_3 b_1   b[a[3]]=b[b]=1  Here b does not have _p
line_4 b_2_p b[a[4]]=b[b]=0
line_5 c_1   b[a[5]]=b[c]=1
line_6 c_2   b[a[6]]=b[c]=1
line_7 c_3   b[a[7]]=b[c]=1 
line_8 d_3_p b[a[8]]=b[d]=0
Result a=0, b=1, c=1, d=0
```

Then for the second file `2` second test

```
$0~a[FNR] && $0~/_p/ {c[++t]=$0" "a[FNR];x[t]=a[FNR]
```

If line does contain corenspondig letter and `_p`, set array `c` to what you like to print and set array `x` to letter.

At last

```
{for (i=1;i<=t;i++) if (b[x[i]]!=1) print c[i],b[x[i]]}
```

Scroll to all number cof counter `t` and look in array `b` if its not true, then print.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But  not all "b" in list2 contain "_p", so output should not contain "b_2_p b" line. Any more suggestions?

Comment: @bin There are one `b_2_p` with `_p` so it is printed out. Other `b_1` line is not printed since it does not contain `_p`. What is then wrong?

Comment: all '^a' line in list2 have "_p$", so we print "a" associated line. Same pattern can be found in '^d' line. But there are two '^b' line, only one end with "_p", so "b" line should not be printed. A little bit complicated. @Jotne

Comment: @bin  This new `awk` should do.  May be shorten some.

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot. However, I can not understand it well. Could you explain it? @Jotne

Comment: @bin did try to explain it some.

Comment: Great. Very detailed answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a set for elements of list1 from which you subtract items of list1 that have a non-compliant correspondance in list2:

```
list1=['a', 'a','b', 'b','c','c','c','d']
list2=['a_1_p', 'a_2_p', 'b_1', 'b_2_p', 'c_1', 'c_2', 'c_3','d_3_p']

matches = set(list1).difference( c for c,e in zip(list1,list2) if not(e.startswith(c) and e.endswith("_p")) )
print(matches)
# {'d', 'a'}
```